# openCV 3.0.0 cv::vector missing

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm upgrading from `opencv 2.4.11` to `3.0.0` I have used `cv::vector` in my code 
`<br>` but now I get the error
vector in not a member of *'cv'*

I will start using `std::vector` instead `<br>`
however I can't find anywhere was it removed or just moved to another header file?

Comment: `cv::vector` it's not an OpenCV type. I'm pretty sure that you just used `std::vector` seen through `cv` namespace

Comment: @Miki what do you mean there was a type named cv::vector...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In OpenCV prior to 3.0, you can see at the beginning of `core.hpp` that OpenCV is using `std::vector` internally:

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_CORE_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_CORE_HPP__

...
#include <vector>
...

/*! \namespace cv
    Namespace where all the C++ OpenCV functionality resides
*/
namespace cv {
...
using std::vector;
...
```

So you can access `std::vector` also through `cv` namespace like:

```
cv::vector
```

In fact, internally OpenCV refers to `std::vector` just as `vector`.

In OpenCV 3.0 instead the `#using std::vector` is not present, and internally OpenCV refers always to `std::vector`.

You'll be able to use `cv::vector` adding this into your code:

```
namespace cv
{
    using std::vector;
}
```

Comment: have they exclude the usage of cv::vector, what used to compile in previous versions

Comment: Still getting: ‘Vec3f’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @sqp Vec3f is a different thing from a vector. Have you tried with cv::Vec3f?