# Calculating the mean and standard deviation in C++ for single channeled histogram

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I want calculate the mean and standard deviations for a histogram of a HSV image but I only want to do this histogram and calculations for the V channel.

I have been reading examples on how to do this for a set of channels and have tried these approaches but I am getting confused over whether my approach for initially creating the histogram is correct or not for just one channel because the program keeps crashing when i try to execute it.

Here is what I have at the moment (The variable test is a cv::Mat image and this can be any image you wish to use to recreate the issue). I have probably missed something obvious and the for loop might not be correct in terms of the range of values but I haven't done this in C++ before.

```
        cv::cvtColor(test, test, CV_BGR2HSV);


        int v_bins = 50;
        int histSize[] = { v_bins };
        cv::MatND hist;

        float v_ranges[] = { 0, 255};
        cv::vector<cv::Mat> channel(3);
        split(test, channel);

        const float* ranges[] = { v_ranges };
        int channels[] = {0};

        cv::calcHist(&channel[2], 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false); //histogram calculation

        float mean=0;

        float rows= hist.size().height;
        float cols = hist.size().width;

        for (int v = 0; v < v_bins; v++)
        {
            std::cout << hist.at<float>(v, v) << std::endl;;
            mean = mean + hist.at<float>(v);
        }

        mean = mean / (rows*cols);
        std::cout << mean<< std::endl;;
```

Comment: cv::vector<cv::Mat> channel(3); ??

Comment: i thought that is necessary because HSV is split into the 3 channels and I only want the V channel for the histogram

Comment: i wonder is there a cv::vector ? or std::vector

Comment: @sturkmen `cv::vector` is fine for OpenCV version prior to 3.0. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400823/opencv-3-0-0-cvvector-missing/33401313#33401313) for details.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use [cv::meanStdDev](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#meanstddev), that calculates a mean and standard deviation of array elements.

Note that both `mean` and `stddev` arguments are `cv::Scalar`, so you need to do `mean[0]` and `stddev[0]` to get the double values of your single channel array `hist`.

This code will clarify it's usage:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat test = cv::imread("path_to_image");

    cv::cvtColor(test, test, CV_BGR2HSV);

    int v_bins = 50;
    int histSize[] = { v_bins };
    cv::MatND hist;

    float v_ranges[] = { 0, 255 };
    cv::vector<cv::Mat> channel(3);
    split(test, channel);

    const float* ranges[] = { v_ranges };
    int channels[] = { 0 };

    cv::calcHist(&channel[2], 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false); //histogram calculation

    cv::Scalar mean, stddev;
    cv::meanStdDev(hist, mean, stddev);

    std::cout << "Mean: " << mean[0] << "   StdDev: " << stddev[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can compute the mean and the standard deviation by their definition:

```
double dmean = 0.0;
double dstddev = 0.0;

// Mean standard algorithm
for (int i = 0; i < v_bins; ++i)
{
    dmean += hist.at<float>(i);
}
dmean /= v_bins;

// Standard deviation standard algorithm
std::vector<double> var(v_bins);
for (int i = 0; i < v_bins; ++i)
{
    var[i] = (dmean - hist.at<float>(i)) * (dmean - hist.at<float>(i));
}
for (int i = 0; i < v_bins; ++i)
{
    dstddev += var[i];
}
dstddev = sqrt(dstddev / v_bins);

std::cout << "Mean: " << dmean << "   StdDev: " << dstddev << std::endl;
```

and you'll get the same values as OpenCV `meanStdDev`.

Comment: Ok. I get an output but to me the results I am getting looks quite weird. i am obtaining a mean of 69271.2 and standard deviation of 86937.1 . Is that realistic for a histogram or has something gone wrong?

Comment: @bardsleyta I updated the answer also with the computation of mean and standard deviation from their definition. You can see that the results are the same as OpenCV. If you don't expect these results, probably you shouldn't compute mean and stddev on the histogram, but on the image.

Comment: ok. I seemed to have misread the mean and standard deviation function and was trying to do it on the histogram rather than on the image. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: what is v_bins?

Comment: @Hossein the number of bins for the "v" channel. See the first snippet

Comment: @Miki: Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about calculating statistics on a histogram. If you just run `meanStdDev`, you'll get the mean and stdev of the bin values. That doesn't tell you an awful lot.

Probably what you want is the mean and stdev intensity.

So, if you want to derive the **image** mean and standard deviation from a histogram (or set of histograms), then you can use the following code:

```
// assume histogram is of type cv::Mat and comes from cv::calcHist

double s = 0;
double total_hist = 0;

for(int i=0; i < histogram.total(); ++i){
    s += histogram.at<float>(i) * (i + 0.5); // bin centre
    total_hist += histogram.at<float>(i);
}

double mean = s / total_hist;

double t = 0;
for(int i=0; i < histogram.total(); ++i){
    double x = (i - mean);
    t += histogram.at<float>(i)*x*x;
}
double stdev = std::sqrt(t / total_hist);
```

From the definitions of the mean:

```
mean = sum(x * p(x)) // expectation
std = sqrt(sum( p(x)*(x - mean)**2 ) // sqrt(variance)
```

The mean is the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) for x. So `histogram[x]/sum(histogram)` gives you `p(x)`. The definition of standard deviation is similar and comes from the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable). The numbers are slightly simpler because pixels can only take integer values and are unit spaced.

Note this is also useful if you want to calculate normalisation statistics for a batch of images using the `accumulate` option.

Adapted from: [How to calculate the standard deviation from a histogram? (Python, Matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786699/how-to-calculate-the-standard-deviation-from-a-histogram-python-matplotlib)