# Find standard deviation and coefficient of variation for a distribution using numpy.std()

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics, standard-deviation

Calculate the S.D. and coefficient of variation (C.V.) for the following table : Class : 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50, 50-60, 60-70, 70-80 Frequency : 5, 10, 20, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5​

I know how to solve this problem using mathematical steps as mentioned here
https://brainly.in/question/36413297.  But how can I solve it using **numpy.std()**.
From the official documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html I can see that **numpy.std()** expects a list of values as input. But in my case, these are class ranges and corresponding frequencies. So how can I apply **numpy.std()** in this kind of non-list input problem?

Comment: please provide your current code

Comment: @mozway since I don't know how to handle this non-list input in numpy.std(), I haven't started the coding yet.

Comment: Your table of data is a histogram.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786699/how-to-calculate-the-standard-deviation-from-a-histogram-python-matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are required to use only the .std() method and no other method, and if your data consist of whole numbers, I suggest you populate your midPoint class list and use the .std() on a single list.

Here is what I mean:

```
import numpy as np
def formatL1n2(L1,L2):
  L3 = []
  for i in range(len(L1)):
    L3.append([L1[i]]*L2[i])
  L4 = [] # this is to format L3
  for i in L3:
    for j in i:
        L4.append(j)
  return L3
L1 = np.array([5,15,25,35,45,55,65,75])
L2 = np.array([5,10,20,40,30,20,10,5])
L3 = formatL1n2(L1,L2)
st = np.std(L3)
print(L3)
```

Output:

```
15.91992077715905
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have not started working on the code. The implementation of that might differ accordingly. But I suggest that you assign the class ranges a single value as the link you have attached for https://brainly.in/question/36413297.

```
def midPoint(l):
   return (l[0]+l[len(l)-1])/2
```

Even the mathematical approach is trying to find the midpoint first.
After having those midPoints you can implement the numpy.std() to get your SD and Var.
Remember upvoting if it solves your question. And give comments if it is still not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Actually, I thought about this method. But even if we move with the middle value-taking approach, again we will face the two lists right? One list for the middle values say  L1=[5,15,25,35,45,55,65] and the second list is the given frequencies list say L2= [5, 10, 20, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5].
But according to numpy.std() documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html,  the std() method expects only single list right?
FYI: I want to solve this problem with numpy.std() method only. No other customized code is allowed