# How to produce binned histogram from vector using std::map in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a std::vector of float which contains 1300 data, i.e. {1.45890123, 1.47820920, 1.48326172, ...}
I would like to build the histogram of the vector using std::map and then plot the histogram with OpenCV. This is how I use std::map to get the count of each data but I have no idea on how to do the binning?

```
size_t frames = 1300
float_t *tdata = (float_t *)malloc(frames * sizeof(float_t));

std::vector<float_t> hdata(tdata, tdata + frames);
std::vector<double> hdata_range, hdata_count;
std::map<float_t, int> hgram;
for (const auto &x : hdata) ++hgram[x];
transform(hgram.begin(), hgram.end(), back_inserter(hdata_range), [](const auto& val){return val.first;});
transform(hgram.begin(), hgram.end(), back_inserter(hdata_count), [](const auto& val){return val.second;});
```

Then I do plotting of the histogram with OpenCV,

```
    Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plot_1b = plot::Plot2d::create(hdata_range, hdata_count);
    plot_1b->setNeedPlotLine(true);
    plot_1b->setShowText(false);
    plot_1b->setShowGrid(false);
    plot_1b->setPlotBackgroundColor(Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    plot_1b->setPlotLineColor(Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    plot_1b->setPlotLineWidth(5);
    plot_1b->setInvertOrientation(true);
    plot_1b->setPlotTextColor(Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    plot_1b->render(cv_display_hdata);
```

A window containing the histogram appears, but since I did not have binning, the counts are generally 1 for each data. But I would like to add binning to the histogram to produce the Gaussian (Normal) distribution histogram.

How can I do that with std::map?

Thanks,
rolly

With the solution by paddy, I am able to produce a much better histogram but the maximum count is different from that of Matlab, any idea why?

[No binning histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpZC9.png)
[Matlab histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWROl.png)
[image: paddy's solution]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a `std::map` for binning data, you can simply choose the bin's starting value as the key. For that, divide by the bin size and then compute the floor. This will give you a whole number uniquely identifying the bin.

```
float_t binsize = 1.0f;
std::map<float_t, int> hgram;
for (auto x : hdata) {
    ++hgram[std::floor(x / binsize)];
}
```

To massage the histogram data range into the form used in your question, just scale the key by the bin size. You can choose whatever single value you want to represent the bin. It might be the start or end value of the bin. Or, in the example below I choose the center of the bin:

```
hdata_range.reserve(hgram.size());
hdata_count.reserve(hgram.size());
for (const auto& keyval : hgram)
{
    hdata_range.push_back((keyval.first + 0.5f) * binsize);
    hdata_count.push_back(keyval.second);
}
```

Comment: The `reserve()` alone deserved an upvote.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much! It works as what I want to get, and a typo may be missing (auto& x : hdata).

Comment: It's not a typo. There's no reason to iterate using references to a primitive type like float. Value is just fine, and actually more efficient unless the compiler realizes what you are doing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I am fairly new to C++. I would also like to count the number of elements in each bin, so that I can find the maximum occurrence. I did minMaxLoc(hdata_count, &min_hcount, &max_hcount); But max_hcount seems different from that I have with Matlab. Am I right in finding max_hcount? Thank you!

Comment: The bins _are_ counts. That's what is being calculated here, and what defines a histogram. Any value allocated to a bin will increase the count for that bin by 1. As for what MatLab does, I have no idea. Based on the image you showed, it looks like MatLab is using a bin size of 0.01. Did you try modifying the bin size in the code I provided? I made that quite explicit so it's easy to change.

Comment: Yes, thank you! You are right, the difference is due to the bin size. As I changed the bin size to that of Matlab, it produce the same count. The only difference is the way OpenCV plots the histogram, how do I produce bar graph with plot2d in OpenCV? Best, rolly

Comment: I don't know. Read the OpenCV docs.

Comment: Hi paddy, one more question on the histogram produced. How can I calculate the mean and standard deviation after binning? Is that true if I have different bin size, it will give different standard deviation? according to this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569323/calculating-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-c-for-single-channeled-histogra

Comment: Same way you would calculate those in ordinary data. Take the center value of each bin, and then assume you have X number of those values where X is the count. Yes, of course bin size affects mean and standard deviation. When you bin data, you lose information because you are essentially quantizing it.