# How to cast from cv::Vec3f to a float type?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, vector, casting

### Background

I am currently trying to build an autonomous drone using *ROS* on my *Rapsberry Pi* which is running an *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS*. Solving the Computer Vision problem of recognising red circles as of now.

### Code

I currently want to convert this:

```
cv::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles
```

into a an array of vectors of floats. However, I am well aware that a simple cast wouldn't suffice. So how should I approach this?

Comment: By using the documented accessors of the cv::vector and cv::Vec classes to copy the floats into your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a simple loop?

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;

// 'circles' filled somehow...

// Get 'circles' as a vector of vector of floats 'v'
std::vector<std::vector<float>> v(circles.size(), std::vector<float>(3));

for(size_t i=0; i<circles.size(); ++i) 
{
    const cv::Vec3f& c = circles[i];             
    v[i][0] = c[0];
    v[i][1] = c[1];
    v[i][2] = c[2];
}
```

---

Don't use `cv::vector`. Use `std::vector` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33401313/5008845) for more details.

Comment: That's not "an array of vectors of floats" that the OP is requesting.

Answer (score 1):

## Data Structure

Before you convert `cv::vector<cv::Vec3f>` type to `float` type

you have to understand what kind of data structure `cv::vector<cv::Vec3f>` 
 is

It's like a 2d vector `std::vector<cv::Vec3f>`

[image]

so you cannot just assign a float variable to a 2d vector

You have to use another 2d vector with float type to store the data content

Comment: Thank you for this late answer! Very Helpful!

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I bumped into the same problem, I also has to thank you for asking this question

Comment: @SharanDuggirala thumbs up